# Travis CI times out on node jasmine tests, but passes locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, travis-ci, jasmine-node

I've been working on a command line app in node that does some file system reads and express app stuff, and all my tests are passing locally, however Travis seems to be having an issue when building (timing out, which is a Jasmine Node thing). Here's what I've got

**.travis.yml**

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '>=0.10'
before_script:
  - npm install -g grunt-cli
  - npm link
script:
  - "grunt --verbose"
```

**sickmerge_spec.js**

```
// Set the test environment
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

// Dependencies
var exec = require('child_process').exec,
    fs = require('fs'),
    version = require('../package.json').version,
    request = require('request');
    // Helper function to exectue the sickmerge cli
    function execSickmerge (options, callback) {
        exec('sickmerge ' + options, function(err, stdout) {
            console.log(stdout);
            callback(stdout);
        });
    }
// ... Lots of other tests that exec the command, test below fails
describe('web application services', function() {
    it('should respond when with a 200 when http requested', function(done) {
        execSickmerge('./spec/fixtures/javascript.js', function() {
            request('http://127.0.0.1:3000/', function(err, response) {
                expect(response.statusCode).toEqual(200);
                done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**The command code**

```
#! /usr/bin/env node
/*
 * sickmerge
 * https://github.com/jgriffith/sickmerge
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2013 jgriffith
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 */

 /*
 * Module Dependencies/Setup
 */
var fs = require('fs'),
    program = require('commander'),
    syntaxOptions = require('./lib/syntax'),
    version = require('./package.json').version,
    fileLocation,
    env = require('./lib/config')();

// Program Setup and Options
program
    .version(version)
    .usage('[options] <conflicted file location>')
    .option('-h, --hostname [value]', 'The host URL you wish to query in the browser (defaults to localhost).')
    .option('-o, --syntaxes', 'Will show the available syntax options for syntax highlighting.')
    .option('-p, --port <n>', 'The port you wish to deploy on (defaults to 3000).', parseInt)
    .option('-s, --syntax [value]', 'The language of the file for syntax highlighting (optional), defaults to no highlighting. Run with "-o" to see the available options.')
    .option('-m, --merge [value]', 'Specify the initial view in the middle (merged) window on instantiation. Valid options are "yours", "theirs", and "both". Defaults to "yours"')
    .parse(process.argv);

// Store the file location so we can persist later
fileLocation = program.args[0];

// For printing available syntax options
function printSyntaxOptions () {
    console.log('Available options include:\n' + syntaxOptions.showSupportedSyntaxes());
    return;
}

// If the user wants to see the syntax options
if (program.syntaxes) {
    printSyntaxOptions();
    return;
}

// No File given, print help since it's required
if (!fileLocation) {
    program.outputHelp();
    return;
}

// Invalid merge option
if (program.merge && ['yours', 'theirs', 'both'].indexOf(program.merge) === -1) {
    console.log('You\'ve specified an invalid initial merged view: "' + program.merge + '".\nPlease use either "yours", "theirs", or "both"');
    return;
}

// Invalid syntax option
if (program.syntax && syntaxOptions.indexOf(program.syntax) === -1) {
    console.log('You\'ve specified an invalid syntax option: ' + program.syntax);
    printSyntaxOptions();
    return;
}

// Read the passed file, strip the git comments, and build the web service
fs.readFile(fileLocation, function(err, result) {
    if (err) return console.log('There was an error loading your file! ' + err);

    // Setup parameters, load additional files
    var hostname = (program.hostname) ? program.hostname : 'localhost',
        port = (program.port) ? program.port : 3000,
        merge = (program.merge) ? program.merge : 'yours',
        extension = fileLocation.split('.').pop(),
        syntax = (program.syntax) ? program.syntax : syntaxOptions.getSyntax(extension),
        threeWayMerge = require('./lib/gitStrip')(result.toString(), merge),
        express = require('express'),
        app = express(),
        path = require('path'),
        open = require('open');   


    // Web server setup
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    // Build the base route for the page
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.render('editor', { 
            title: fileLocation, 
            syntax: syntax,
            body: threeWayMerge 
        });
    });

    // Post route for saving the file (this is final) and closes the process
    app.post('/save', function (req, res) {
        var content = req.body.content;
        fs.writeFile(fileLocation, content, function (err) {
            if (err) throw "There was an issues saving your file: " + err;
            res.send('complete');
            process.exit();
        });
    });

    // Get route for cancelling the file (this is final) and closes the process
    app.get('/cancel', function (req, res) {
        res.send('terminated');
        process.exit();
    });

    console.log(
        'Sickmerge is waiting for changes.\n' +
        'Visit http://' + hostname + ':' + port + '/ in your browser to make changes\n' +
        'Pressing "Save" or "Cancel" will do the action and close the sickmerge program.\n'+
        'Press CTRL+C if you\'ve closed your web browser and didn\'t click either of those buttons.'
    );
    app.listen(port);
    if( env !== 'test') open('http://' + hostname + ':' + port);
});
```

You can also see [the code on github](https://github.com/joelgriffith/sickmerge/tree/unit-tests), and the [builds in Travis](https://travis-ci.org/joelgriffith/sickmerge). I originally thought app.list() was preventing execution of the console, but removing it didn't work either.

Does Travis just block certain ports? Does it not allow filesystem queries?

Comment: I would guess that request('http://127.0.0.1:3000/' is making the timeout ? Maybe you should use supertest instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [the current script](https://github.com/joelgriffith/sickmerge/blob/master/.travis.yml) is working which is:

**.travis.yml**

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '>=0.10'
before_install:
  - npm install -g grunt-cli
before_script:
  - npm link
script:
  - "grunt --verbose"
```

> Does it not allow filesystem queries?

Travis-CI does allow filesystem queries.